# AppEngine Image API: dynamic transformations and quotas

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm currently working with the [Image API on GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/), and we need some thumbnails. I've read that we can use dynamic transformations to resize and crop the image dynamically by specifying the arguments in the URL to save some storage:

```
# Resize the image to 32 pixels (aspect-ratio preserved)
http://lhx.ggpht.com/randomStringImageId=s32
```

I was wondering if subsequent calls to the same URL are counting against the **Transformations Executed** quotas? If so, that will kill the purpose of it.

Answer (score 0):

Without the transformation result being saved (and nothing in the docs mentions anything like that) it means subsequent requests for the same result will require repeating the transformation, so I'd expect them to count towards the Transformations Executed quota.

In general storage is cheaper than other paid GAE resources. If you're concerned about Transformations Executed quota, depending on the expected thumbnails request pattern it may be worthy teaching your app to act as a middle man for the thumbnails, itself requesting the transformations and persisting the transformation results, maybe just for a while, to avoid (some) subsequent transformations (instead of just refering the clients to the transforming URLs, that is).

Comment: That was my first assumption but I'm expecting that the "highly optimized image delivery network" is caching the transformation. Let's wait for an answer from the app-engine team... Otherwise, I'll run a script to know the hard way.